# angularjs error argument 'controller' is not a function got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Hello I've been searching for reason why my code doesn't work but i can't find it. I've found similar question posted here but non help.
This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AngularJs tests</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="blog"><br>

        <br>

        {{blog}}
<script>
    var app=angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller=('Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.blog="text";
    }]);
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What's the difference between the expected behavior and the observed behavior?

Comment: My expression should return value "text" but it stays in HTML like {{blog}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.controller = ( ... );` is not valid syntax.

`app.controller('Ctrl', ...);`

Comment: But as it is written above it's from tutorial of angular so it should be valid I still don't see my mistake :(

Comment: Well that tutorial must be wrong, because `app.controller = ` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Here is your exact code, with the controller declaration reworked to how I mention (i.e., all I did was remove the equal sign) and it works [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/tohugekovo/1/)

Comment: Thank you:). you are right is there some way how to find these small bugs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this your controller changnge to

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.blog="text";
    }]);
```